# How can I monitor a named pipe?

Tags: windows, penetration-test

I have installed an application that opens a named pipe that is accessible over the network. I would like to monitor/sniff what is sent to this named pipe, any idea how I can do that?

Edit: Even though it is accessible over the network, the application talks to it on the local machine.

Comment: Similar question here. http://superuser.com/questions/313684/sniff-process-communication

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [tutorial on using WinDbg](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6084/Windows-Debuggers-Part-1-A-WinDbg-Tutorial) to debug via named pipe:

> Doing remote debugging using WinDbg is easy and can be done in one of
>   a number of ways. In the following, ‘debugging server’ is the debugger
>   running on the machine where you’d like to debug; ‘debugging client’
>   is the debugger controlling the session.
>
> To start a server:
>
> ```
> - WinDbg –server npipe:pipe=pipename (note: multiple clients can connect), or
> - from within WinDbg: .server npipe:pipe=pipename (note: single client can connect)
> ```

Comment: This alone does not allow monitoring of named pipes, and since no password was supplied it will decrease the security of your server by exposing the kernel to unauthenticed users

Comment: Why would the debugging be run on a live production server? From the OP's edit, it seemed he was not intending for network access to be used in his testing.

Comment: I don't get any indication that he is testing, even then it might even be off topic

Comment: He asked how to eavesdrop on any named pipe, not how to start windbg server so that windbg clients can talk to it via named pipe. That's completely unrelated.